# vb.net call specific string from function

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

i have this code:

```
Function f1(ByVal x As String, ByVal o As String)
    x = "me"
    o = "you"
    Return {x.ToString, o.ToString}
End Function

Function f2()
    Dim a As String = "i love" & f1(Nothing, ToString)
End Function
```

i'm trying to get string (o) from function f1() to use it in f2() but not working.

Comment: Have you tried turning option strict on? It can help you see the problems.

Comment: @the_lotus yes it said i can't convert type string() to the type string

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do and which part of that you're having trouble with.  Could you expand and rephrase your question?

Comment: Exactly. f1 returns an array of string, you can't concatenate an array to a string. Also, passing me.ToString to f1 doesn't make much sense...

Comment: @the_lotus how i can return a string from f1 also how i can call it, and f1 has two strings in it i just want to call (o)

Comment: What do you mean you're trying to call (o) from f1?  "Call" a string?  I don't know what that means, nor is it clear why you can't do it, whatever that is.

Comment: @StevenDoggart i want to use string (o) from f1() in f2(), but i don't know the problem

Comment: So, what would you expect `a` to equal after it executes the line in f2?  "I love you"?  If so, why would you expect it to be that?  Why wouldn't it be "I love me"?  What about the way you wrote it makes you think it would return o instead of x?

Comment: (I'm not trying to be difficult.  I'm honestly trying to help.  I'm trying to understand where your confusion is coming from.  Clearly you are way off base on this, and @the_lotus already explained where the problem is, but that wasn't enough to help you.  So I'm hoping if you at least explain why you think it _should_ work that way, we'd stand a chance of explaining to you why that's not the case.)

Comment: @StevenDoggart i want it to be "i love you" not "i love me", that's why i need just "o" not "x", also if you can write a working code for me that would be appreciated

Comment: Ah.  I get it now.  I think you're confusing parameters with return values.  They are two completely different things.  Parameters are inputs and return values are outputs.  The stuff between the parenthesis are parameters, not return values.  So, when you say `f1(Nothing, ToString)`, that's sending `Nothing` and `Me.ToString` as inputs into the function.  They have no bearing on the output value that the statement evaluates to.  The function evaluates to whatever the function returns, and so that's what get's concatenated into the `a` string.

Comment: Since your function always returns the same array, it's always going to evaluate to the same thing, regardless of the input parameters.

Comment: If you're legitimately trying to learn how to program, that should be enough to point you in the right direction.  If you aren't trying to learn how to program, and you're just looking for someone to write the code for you so you can move on to other non-development things.  That's fine.  I respect that, but that's not the purpose of this site.  There are plenty of micro-consulting sites where you can hire a programmer to do the work for you, if that's what you're interested in doing.

Comment: Please do not vandalize posts, even your own.

Answer (score 2):

You should turn Option Strict On since there's a lot of errors with the sample.

```
Function f1(ByVal x As String, ByVal o As String) As String() ' x and o are useless parameters
    x = "me"
    o = "you"
    Return {x.ToString, o.ToString} ' Returns an array of string
End Function

Function f2() ' Method not returning anything
    Dim a As String = "i love" & f1(Nothing, Me.ToString()).ToString() ' Can't really concatenate an array to a string. Also, parameter Me.ToString() doesn't make much sense
End Function
```

I suggest you start with something more simple like this.

```
Function f1() As String
    Dim o As String = "you"
    Return o
End Function

Function f2() As String
    Dim a As String = "I love " & f1()
    Return a
End Function
```

Then add a parameter to select different return value

```
Function f1(ByVal mustReturnX As Boolean) As String
    Dim x As String = "me"
    Dim o As String = "you"

    If mustReturnX Then
        Return x
    End If

    Return o
End Function

Function f2() As String
    Dim a As String = "i love " & f1(True)
    Return a
End Function
```

Without clear requirements, we can't help more.

Answer (score 0):

A Function needs a return value type. Comments and explanation in line.

```
Function f1() As String()
    'Declares and initializes an array of 2 strings 
    Dim myWords As String() = {"me", "you"}
    'Returns the array to the calling code
    Return myWords
End Function

Function f2() As String
    'assigns the value of f1 to a local array
    Dim words() As String = f1()
    'concatenates the second element of the array
    'arrays in .net are zero based meaning that the
    'first element is element (0) the second is element (1) etc.
    'and returns the string to whatever code called f2
    Return "i love" & words(1)
End Function
```